# Python Telegram как получить статистику по пригласительным ссылкам

Tags: python, telegram

Всем привет! Сейчас интересуюсь аналитикой рекламы телеграм каналов и передо мной поставили задачу: автоматизировать процесс подсчета статистики по пригласительным ссылкам. В интерфейсе администратора тг канала это выглядит так как на фото 1.
Нужно получить название каждой ссылки и количество вступивших.

[image: фото 1]

Помимо этого надо получить никнеймы тех, кто вступил и дату вступления, как на фото 2.
Подскажите, в каком направлении двигаться, я просмотрел api telegram, но не нашел, что искал. Буду рад любой помощи!

[image: фото 2]

Answer (score 0):

**Это возможно сделать только в приватных каналах!**

Используй метод `createChatInviteLink`, который создаёт ссылку и при использовании ее для приватного канала возвращается `[chat_join_request]`, в котором: данные пользователя, время, ссылка.

Comment: То есть с уже имеющимися ссылками и в публичном канале такого сделать нельзя?

Comment: Нельзя, только как я написал в сообщении. Если помог, отметь мой ответ галкой справа

Comment: Я вот сейчас пытаюсь разобраться и не вижу, чтобы `createChatInviteLink` возвращал `[chat_join_request]`. Подскажи пожалуйста, как до этого дойти? [https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chatinvitelink] тут нет такого параметра